# The final number after $999$ operations.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, recreational-mathematics

I wanted to know, let the numbers $1,\frac12,\frac13,\dots,\frac1{1000}$ be written on a blackboard. One may delete two arbitrary numbers $a$ and $b$ and write $a+b+ab$ instead. After $999$ such operations only one number is left. What is this final number.

I tried, let $*$ be an operation $a*b = (1+a)(1+b) - 1$, and $(a*b)*c = (1+a)(1+b)(1+c) -1$. by induction we can show that for $N$ such no.s we have $(1+a)(1+b)(1+c)\dots(1+d) - 1$, where $n\{a,b,c,\dots,d\} = N$. In the question we have numbers $1,\frac12,\frac13,\dots,\frac1{1000}$. plugging in we get the final number $1000$, but the answer given is $100$.

What am i doing wrong?

Any help appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: I agree. You're induction works as well, so the final number is $$\prod\limits_{i=1}^{1000}\frac{i+1}{i}-1=1000$$

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Your answer is correct. We have
$$
1*(1/2)*(1/3)*\cdots*(1/1000)=\frac21\cdot\frac32\cdots\frac{1001}{1000}-1=1001-1=1000.
$$

Comment: The key observation here is that the operation $*$ is both commutative and associative. Therefore the order in which the numbers get paired up is immaterial.

Comment: The only thing preventing $(\mathbb Q, *)$ from being an abelian group, is that $-1$ has no inverse :(

Comment: @Tomas: Yes, because (as the OP more or less observes) $(\Bbb{Q},*)$ is isomorphic to $(\Bbb{Q},\cdot)$, the isomorphism being $x\mapsto x+1$.