# The numbers $1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},\dots,\frac{1}{100}$ are written on a white board

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> The numbers $1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},\dots,\frac{1}{n}$ are written on a white board. In every step we pick two numbers $a$ and $b$ and put $a+b+ab$ besides. Prove that the last number that remains is $n$.

By induction it is easy to prove:

It is true for $1$.

Think it is true for $n$

Prove it is true for $n+1$

$n+\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{n}{n+1}=n+1$

But I want a non-induction prove.Thanks.

Comment: I don't think your proof is complete, you are assuming the last step is the only one that involves $\frac{1}{n+1}$

Comment: I agree. You inductive step requires $n+1$ to be the last number to be paired with the result of pairing all others.

Comment: @Carry on Smiling Yes it is wrong can you give a right induction prove?

Comment: The title doesn't match the question. The title appears to use $n=100$ as an example, but that's never mentioned in the question.

Comment: Your description of the process is very unclear. E.g., the number $n$ is not written on the board. What are we supposed to do when $a$ and $b$ are on the board, but $a+b+ab$ isn't? Etcetera.

Comment: I'm baffled by your explanation, how is 1 ever going to be paired with anything?  You can't add anything to it that will them match - give us an example of picking a and b with numbers in it

Comment: $1 = 1/2 + 1/3 + 1/2*3$ can match 1.  But many numbers won't match anything. So you can pick numbers that match nothing forever.  Also if you remove the 1/2 before you remove the 1.  You will never remove the 1 later.  And finally as 1/n < 1/k then $1/n \ne 1/k + 1/j + 1/jk$ so 1/n will never be picked ever.  So if anything is last it will be 1/n but it's not that case that anything has to be last.

Comment: I think this is a duplicate [of an older question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/431520/11619). As this is slightly more general and I answered that original, I will refrain from casting a close vote here.

Comment: Ah, the original is much clearer.  I had no idea what the OP was asking. @TahaAkbari  Your induction doesn't work.  You are assuming 1/(n+1) will be the last number combined.  That need not be the case.  Induction is actually hard as hell I think.  But if you prove first that order doesn't matter induction is easy.

Comment: How to pick up/delete two numbers when $n=1$?
For $n=2$, $\frac{5}{2}$ remains.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note that

$$a+b+ab=(a+1)(b+1)-1$$

So, in the end after all operations, we get

$$(a_1+1)(a_2+1) \cdots (a_n+1) -1=\prod_{i=1}^{n}\left(1+\frac1i\right)-1=(n+1)-1=n$$

Comment: @PatrickStevens Thanks for fixing the typo.

Answer (score 6):

Notice that $(ab+a+b)+1=(a+1)(b+1)$, which means that the product of all numbers increased by $1$, is an invariant.

Initially, this product is
$$\prod_{k=1}^n\left(\frac1k+1\right)=\prod_{k=1}^n\frac{k+1}k=n+1$$
by [telescoping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series), so the last number is always $n$.