# A Gift Problem for the Year 2018

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, summation, finite-groups, harmonic-numbers

We had this problem in exam  class  yesterday on Combinatoric  and it was supposed to be the new year gift from our teacher. The exercise was entitled **A Gift Problem for the Year 2018**

> **Problem:**
>
> The numbers  $1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{4},\cdots,\frac{1}{2018} $ are written on the blackboards. John chooses any two numbers say $x$ and $y$ erases them and writes the number $x+y+xy$.
>   He continues to do so until there is only one number left on the board.
>   What are the possible value of the final number?

I understood the problem as follows for instance if John take $x=1$ and $y=\frac{1}{2}$ then $x+y+xy =2$ and the new list becomes $$2,\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{4},\cdots,\frac{1}{2018} $$ 
 continuing like this and so on.....

Please bear with me  that I do not want to propose my solution since I fell like it was wrong and I don't want to fail the exam before the result get out. but by the way I found, $2017$, $2018$ and $2019$ but I am still suspicious.

You may help is you have an idea.

Comment: Please show your work even if it is not correct. That way we can help and find any errors.

Comment: Since we are not in your class, how about an *actual title*?

Comment: Something more descriptive of the actual mathematical problem?

Comment: It's your question.

Comment: Okay, then therefore it's my downvote until you find a better title.

Comment: Not my responsibility, mate.

Comment: @GuyFsone I suggested a new title. I hope it's better now. Cheers!

Comment: What's the excuse for rejecting the title suggested by @AccidentalFourierTransform, is it not click baity enough?

Comment: Essentially a duplicate of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/431520/11619). Since I answered that one I will refrain from casting the first vote to close.

Comment: [A later variant](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1880198/11619) with the same idea.

Comment: I removed my downvote. I hope that the other users who downvoted because of title-related issues will do the same soon.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Don't think you would still say the same now.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Consider the multiplicative  law on $\Bbb R$ defines by $$x*y =x+y+xy =(x+1)(y+1)-1 $$

you can check that it is **associative and commutative** on $\Bbb R$. Therefore at the end the remaining number is 
$$\begin{align}x_0*x_1*x_2*\cdots x_{2018} &= 1*\frac{1}{2}*\frac{1}{3}*\cdots *\frac{1}{2018} \\&=\left[\prod_{i=1}^{2018}(1+x_i)\right]-1\\
&=\left[\prod_{i=1}^{2018}\left(1+\frac{1}{i}\right)\right]-1 \\
&=\frac{2}{1}\cdot \frac{3}{2}\cdot \frac{4}{3}\cdot \ldots \cdot \frac{2018+1}{2018}-1=\color{red}{2019-1=2018.}
\end{align}$$

Comment: This works with any number, btw. Not just 2018.

Comment: you are right it actually a telescopic product.  there is no reason to restrict it to 2018

Answer (score 39):

Hint: Note that $xy+x+y = (x+1)(y+1) - 1$. In particular, this implies that at any stage of the process, if all the numbers on the board are $\{a_1, \cdots, a_k\}$, then the product $$(a_1 + 1) (a_2 + 1) \cdots (a_k + 1)$$ is **invariant**, i.e. it doesn't change when you erase two numbers $x$, $y$, and replace them with $xy+x+y$. What does this imply the final number *must* be?

Comment: It's 2018, @JohnLou You have to subtract the one again.

Comment: Is $(1+1)(1/2+1)\cdots(1/2018+1)$ computed by rewriting things as $(2)(3/2)(4/3)\cdots(2019/2018)$ and recognizing that it telescopes?

Comment: Thanks @ThomasAndrews